# i2c LCD connected to the internet

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3, i2c, lcd

i am trying to display internet connection if it is connected or not in the i2c lcd but when i try to run the code it will not show/display anything. Tried other codes to see if my lcd is working but it does.

```
import I2C_LCD_driver
import urllib.request
mylcd = I2C_LCD_driver.lcd()
def connect(host='http://google.com'):
    try:
        urllib.request.urlopen(host).read() #Python 3.x
        return True
    except:
        return False
# test
    mylcd.lcd_display_string ('connected' if connect() else 'no internet!')
```

Answer (score 0):

It is better to place the function call outside the function body and `if` statement not as an argument. Check this :

```
import I2C_LCD_driver
import urllib.request
mylcd = I2C_LCD_driver.lcd()
def connect(host='http://google.com'):
    try:
        urllib.request.urlopen(host).read() #Python 3.x
        return True
    except:
        return False
# test
if connect() :
    mylcd.lcd_display_string ('connected' )
else :
    mylcd.lcd_display_string ('no internet!')
```